# Add namespaced attribute in modular way

Tags: java, jaxb

for the xml:

```
<foo xmlns="http://ns.com"
     xmlns:ext="http://ext.com"
     attr="xxx"
     ext:bar="yyy">
</foo>
```

How can I create a Foo class? Specifically, I'd like to be able to separate the 'ext' attribute somehow so it is not directly in Foo, but in another class, and in a typesafe way (so not XmlAnyAttribute).

What I optimally wish for is:

```
class Foo {
  Ext ext;
}

class Ext {
  String bar;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a POJO field/property with `@XmlAttribute` if the referenced object has only one mapped field/property with `@XmlValue`.

**Foo**

```
class Foo {
    @XmlAttribute(namespace="http://www.ext.com")
    Ext ext
}
```

**Ext**

```
class Ext {
    @XmlValue
    String bar;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Namespaces

---

**UPDATE**

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

> What if i want to map several attributes?

You can leverage the `@XmlPath` extension in MOXy for this use case:

**Foo**

Using `@XmlPath(".")` indicates that you want the target object represented at the same level in the XML document as the source object.

```
class Foo {
    @XmlPath(".")
    Ext ext
}
```

**Ext**

```
class Ext {
    @XmlAttribute
    String foo;

    @XmlAttribute
    String bar;
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: What if i want to map several attributes?

Comment: How do I specify that Ext belongs in a different namespace?

Comment: @IttayD - The following should help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html